# Running Multiple fsockopen on single page in PHP

Tags: php, performance, asynchronous, fsockopen

I am having a difficulties using fsockopen in PHP, its working fine when I am using a Single fsockopen on a page, but its really very slow if I am using more than one fsockopen.

I have to check the internet connections on a page with ip and port, it can be multiple means it can be more than 100.

So when its running sometimes it goes out of execution time(because I am using less data now), but it will always crash if I will use more IP's.
Its checking one by one, but I want it to run asynchronously like AJAX.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Then run it in ajax - dynamically. Sending a "bunch"/one request at a time and generating the content into your DOM

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? what is your general scenario?

Comment: I am trying to implement a software which will be connected with lots of access points, gateways with their IP's and I have to check whether they are connected with Internet or not by fsockopen.